# set priorities of different tasks in yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto

My question is about priority setting in yocto. I want to set priority for my task or for new recipe. I want that my application runs all time on my device. So can i set priority as per my requirement. Can anyone do help??

Comment: Are you takling about priority of an application that is built using yocto or about priorities of recipes of the yocto build?

Comment: Or even the systemd configuration of the service?

Answer (score 1):

> I want that my application runs all time on my device

This has nothing to do with yocto itself, this is up to the OS that is running your application. If you use [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) you can add a service file that starts your application at boot time. To link systemd to your service, and have yocto place your service file in the image systemd package and enable it at boot, create your service file in your application files directory, or wherever, and in your recipe add:

```
inherit systemd
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "my-app.service"
```

and in the `do_install` part, add something like:

```
install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/my-app.service ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/
```

If you're not using systemd, then it depends on how your system is initialized; if you are using systemd but don't know what it does, then follow the link above and learn about it.